# how to get the parent document if there is a match in referenced array

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

My mongoose schema is as below:

foodTruckUserAttach.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const foodTruck = require('./foodtruck.js');
const foodTruckUser = require('./foodTruckUser.js');


const foodTruckUserAttached = new Schema({
    foodtruck_users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true
    }],
    foodtruck_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'foodtruck',
        required: true
    }
}, {
    versionKey: false
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('foodtruckRegisteredUsers', foodTruckUserAttached);
```

Now what I want here is suppose particular document of **foodTruckUserAttach** has **foodtruck_user** with ids 1,2,3. Now what I want is, I want to return that particular document if it has **foodtruck_user** with id=3. can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foodTruckUserAttached.find({foodtruck_users: 3}, function(err, ftua){
    if(!err){
        console.log(ftua)
    }
});
```